# possible to specify platform dependent package data in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

The title kind of says it all.  If I have a pyproject.toml file:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"somemodule.somepackage" = ["somedataforwindowsonly.ext"]  # can I do this only for windows or linux or whatever?
```

can I specify the package data separately for each platform?